# Numpy multi-slice using C API?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-c-api

I know how to get a slice from a Numpy array using the C API this way:

```
    // 'arr' is a 2D Python array, already created
    PyObject pyArray = PyArray_FromAny(arr, PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_FLOAT), 0, 0, NPY_ARRAY_DEFAULT, null);

    PyObject slice = PySlice_New(PyLong_FromLong(0), PyLong_FromLong(2), null);
    PyObject result = PyObject_GetItem(pyArray, slice);
```

This basically matches the following Python expression:

```
    arr[0:2]
```

Now, how can I get a "multi" slice from 'arr'? For instance, how can programmatically write the following expression?

```
    arr[0:2,0:3]
```

Comment: I'm not sure and cannot test it, but can you try to create a tuple of slices and call GetItem passing the tuple?

Comment: Slice creation works fine with two tuples (instead of two integers), with both tuples containing two integers. Calling PyObject_GetItem with these tuples results in the following error: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: Sorry but maybe I was not clear: create the two slices `PyObject slice_a = PySlice_New(PyLong_FromLong(0), PyLong_FromLong(2), null);` and `PyObject slice_b = PySlice_New(PyLong_FromLong(0), PyLong_FromLong(3), null);`, then create a tuple like `PyObject tuple = PyTuple_Pack(2, slice_a, slice_b)` and then call `PyObject result = PyObject_GetItem(pyArray, tuple);`

Comment: My apology. I tried what you said, GetItem does succeed, but I get a crash when trying to print the result with: `PyDict_SetItemString(globals, "result", result); PyRun_SimpleStringFlags("print(result, flush=True)", null);` (printing code succeeds when my slice is 1D)

Comment: The rationale behind this is that the `__getitem__` in python(3) has signature `__getitem__(self, key)` and it is "not allowed" `__getitem__(self, key_1, key_2)`, thus in `array[0:2,0:3]` I suspect it is actually `array.__getitem__(self,key = (slice(0,2), slice(0,3)))`

Comment: What is the return value of `PyDict_SetItemString`?

Comment: Also I suspect that the result of `getitem` has been garbage collected when you try to print.

Comment: Matteo, it works. The fact that the code was crashing was a side effect but the 1D-code that was still executed previously. Thanks a lot for your valuable help. Still learning Python, I understand a comma means nothing special except the argument is just a tuple! Thanks again.

Comment: Happy that we sorted that out, thank you for testing my suggestions.

Comment: How can I mark your second post as answer?

Comment: I wrote an answer for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get multi dimensional slices you have to insert the slices in a tuple, the call the get item on that tuple. Something like:

```
PyObject* pyArray = PyArray_FromAny(arr, PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_FLOAT), 0, 0, NPY_ARRAY_DEFAULT, null);

PyObject* slice_0 = PySlice_New(PyLong_FromLong(0), PyLong_FromLong(2), null);
PyObject* slice_1 = PySlice_New(PyLong_FromLong(0), PyLong_FromLong(3), null);
PyObject* slices = PyTuple_Pack(2, slice_0, slice_1);

PyObject* result = PyObject_GetItem(pyArray, slices);
```

The rationale behind it is the `__getitem__(self, arg)` (there is a single argument) thus multiple indexes are implicitly converted in a tuple: `arg = (slice(0,2), slice(0,3),)`